# Change process name while executing a python script

Tags: python

I have some python script name abc.py, but when I execute it, I want to run with some different name, say "def".

Is it possible in python without installing any additional module (procname)?

Comment: Why cannot you just rename the file and run? A more detailed requirement would be required :)

Comment: Using procname is the correct answer. Why don't you want to use this module?

Comment: @Kay: This module doesn't come with default python package. This module has to be additionally installed on machine, which cant be done due to some permission reasons.

Comment: I had a look at the source for the module. It's using system calls in c - which I'm guessing is the only way to get the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) calls:

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(None)
prctl = lib.prctl
prctl.restype = ctypes.c_int
prctl.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_ulong,
                  ctypes.c_ulong, ctypes.c_ulong]

def set_proctitle(new_title):
    result = prctl(15, new_title, 0, 0, 0)
    if result != 0:
        raise OSError("prctl result: %d" % result)
```

Compare:

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html
- http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/prctl.h#L53